# How to call onReceive from onReceive of another BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver, android-connectivitymanager

I am developing one android application, In which i need to call onReceive method of Alarmmanager from onReceive of another BroadcastReceiver i.e. Internet connectivity. Is it possible ? Or should i duplicate all my stuff in another BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new intent from onReceive to trigger another broadcast receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent("com.domain.yourboardcastreceiver");
    context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OnReceive(..) method of Internet Connectivity broadcast receiver, you can set alarm and thats how alarm manager will get triggered, eg :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), **AlarmReceiver**.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Don't forget to register alarmmanager's receiver in your manifest file.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you, but i have used @Rex Lam's solution